# Noob CSS question about classes implementation in html file

Tags: html, css

I'm just starting to learn html and may have a super nooby question...
Here is my header in CSS file:

```
h1.heading {
    color: indianred;
}
```

I link it to my html file this way, but it doesn't seem to work

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<h1> BeeHaven Apiaries </h1>
```

Comment: You need a class attribute on your h1

Comment: I would suggest reading up on css selectors on mdn

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is that you have not properly configured your HTML and CSS selectors.

---

The issue is that you have forgotten to add a `class` attribute to your `h1` tag.

```html
<h1 class="heading">Heading!</h1>
```

This is the issue, because in your CSS, you are referencing it with `.heading`.

```css
h1.heading {
  color: indianred;
}
```

Basically, your CSS code means that it will select an element that is a `h1` and has a class (`.`) of `heading`.

This is your fully working code.

```css
h1.heading {
  color: indianred;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="heading">BeeHaven Apiaries</h1>
```

---

Another solution that you can do is to edit the CSS instead of the HTML.

In the CSS, simply remove the `class` selector to avoid getting the `class` attribute, and only get `h1` tags.

```css
h1 {
  color: indianred;
}
```

**Warning!** Please be aware of the consequences this approach has. All `h1` tags will have the styles defined in the CSS.

The finished code should look like this.

```css
h1 {
  color: indianred;
}
```

```html
<h1>BeeHaven Apiaries</h1>
```

---

In summary, there are two solutions for making your code work.

The first one will edit the HTML, and add a `class` attribute so that the CSS can find it properly.

The second solution edits the CSS so that it'll get all of the `h1` tags in the entire HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<h1> BeeHaven Apiaries </h1> 

/* CSS */
h1 {
    color: indianred;
}
```

OR

```
<!-- HTML -->
<h1 class = "heading"> BeeHaven Apiaries </h1> 

/* CSS */
h1.heading {
    color: indianred;
}
```